# Use Responsive Lightbox for FooGallery in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, image-gallery

I have multiple galleries which made by **FooGalllery**, Now i want show the galleries images by **"Responsive Lightbox by dFactory"** plugin. also I installed **Swypebox**!

but the lightbox shows only first image of each gallery!

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution [here, in the WordPress suport forums](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/foo-gallery-and-responsive-lightbox-by-dfactory?replies=10#post-7391394).

In essence, you need to hook into FooGallery's `foogallery_attachment_html_link_attributes` hook.

NOTE: If you had previously selected another lightbox (e.g. FooBox) for any gallery, you must edit that gallery and set the lightbox to "None". Otherwise, I found that both FooBox and RL by dFactory will fire, giving you odd results (perhaps including what you encountered). Hope this helps.

Comment: This link does not directly address the question